# How to use Gmail having 2 step verification with Outlook.com

Tags: gmail, google-account, multi-factor-auth, pop3

Recently I have shifted from Hotmail to the new [Outlook.com](http://Outlook.com). It supports adding multiple POP3 emails into it. I have successfully added my Gmail into it (you can refer the steps ***[here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/gmail-outlook-dot-com-hotmail/)***). But my gmail inbox mails are not getting displayed and it returns a blank inbox for Gmail.

I tried both the default and advanced methods to add my email. Is this something related with 2-step verification? [Here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) is an article about setting up POP in mail client and is mentioning about some application passwords for mails with 2 step verification [here](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833). How do I add my Gmail with 2-step verification so I can view messages on outlook.com?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the [linked](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833) you'll have to generate a one-time [application-specific password](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en_GB#accesscodes) and provide that application-specific password as your password when you're adding the Gmail account.

*Note I haven't tried this for **outlook.com** but the practice is standard for across all clients which request for password & don't request for the token code using Google's 2-factor auth*

Answer (score 3):

Google makes this possible.

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security, and click on the "Sign In and Security" header in the left sidebar.

Then in the "Password and Sign In Method" card, select "App Passwords"

Select the environment you are creating this for (i.e. Windows Computer)

Then it will generate a password for you. When you set up your POP3 in Outlook, use this password, not your regular email login password. And you're set!